# Use of macros but had implicit declaration of function error

Tags: c

I'm trying to run the following code, but I cannot compile it as my IDE complained for the following reason.

> H:\C\sandBox.c|11|warning:
>   implicit declaration of function
>   'RECIPROCAL'|

I don't know why my code doesn't work. Can you please help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
# RECIPROCAL(number) (1.0 / (number))

int main()
{
    float   counter;    /* Counter for our table */

    for (counter = 0.0; counter < 10.0;
     counter += 1.0) {

        printf("1/%f = %f\n", counter, RECIPROCAL(counter));
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot `define`:

```
#define RECIPROCAL(number) (1.0 / (number))
```

Comment: It doesn't work in Xcode 4.2 with the Clang compiler. Im using the DLog macro with #define in front but after a clean it still says implicit declaration of function. Help!

Answer (score 3):

That’s because you need to use `#define` to define a preprocessor macro.

Change:

```
# RECIPROCAL(number) (1.0 / (number))
```

to

```
#define RECIPROCAL(number) (1.0 / (number))
```